# Convert & Burn M2TS files into DVD format WITHOUT LOSS

Tags: video, conversion, dvd, bluray

I have my marriage film (Resolution: 1080p /Format: .m2ts / File size: 7 GB) on a bluray disc which I ripped in my HDD with this software that I found on forums.

The thing is that I want to make some copies for the family who still have DVD players. So I came up with the idea to burn the BDR disc into DVD to be played in any DVD player but without any loss at all. Is there any hack to do this? I have blank DVDs of 8.5GB enough to burn my video.

I know that DVD format is at 420p resolution in NTSC but I wonder if there is a procedure to convert/simulate/hack this in order to play my BDR video in a DVD at full high quality? I don't want to compress the video, just transform the format to be recognized in DVD players because as I said my BDR file is 7GB enough to fit in a 8.5GB DVD disc.

Also I need to rebuild the menu and the scenes with a video editor. Can you suggests also a good video editor? I heard about Corel video editor and Pineapple.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Whatever else you may be facing, one big obstacle is the DVD players themselves. They're not designed to output 1080p. Even if you could get the image onto them in Bluray format, they couldn't output it. (If they're really Bluray players, then you don't need any hacks, just a dupe of the image.)

If the content is something they want to see, people will be pleased to get standard DVDs regardless of the quality.